# Can you style html form buttons with css?

Tags: html, css, forms

I don't like the default button style. It's really boring. I am using

```
<input type="submit">
```

type buttons. Can I style these somehow in css? If not, the other way of doing it i guess would be to use a div instead, and make it a link. How do you make those work with forms?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can achieve your desired through easily by CSS :-

**HTML**

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Application" id="submit" />
```

**CSS**

```
#submit {
    background-color: #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius:6px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border:none;
}



#submit:hover {
    border: none;
    background:red;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #777;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbZ3r/6/)

Comment: can I do the same with text inputs and textareas?

Comment: @Xzar why not sure you can edit can customize the design of text inputs and textarea easily by CSS.....

Answer (score 19):

Yeah, it's pretty simple:

```
input[type="submit"]{
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
```

I recommend giving it an ID or a class so that you can target it more easily.

Comment: Some styling (IE: Text-Shadow) won't be applied via class, and only work if you target the input type directly.

Comment: Not working for me in IE11. It'll take everything but the text-shadow, but targeting directly on the input type applies it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can target those specificaly using `input[type=submit]` e.g.

```
.myFormClass input[type=submit] {
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: @candiancreed The `input` elements would need to be children of the element with the class. I have this selector working in plenty of projects. Can you create an example and post a question?

Answer (score 3):

You can directly create your own style in this way:

```
 input[type=button]
 { 
//Change the style as you like
 }
```

Comment: I think this won't work -- OP used type=submit, not type=button.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

if you need it looking consistent on Mobile Safari...

Answer (score 0):

write the below style into same html file head section or write into a .css file

```
<style type="text/css">
.submit input
    {
    color: #000;
    background: #ffa20f;
    border: 2px outset #d7b9c9
    }
</style>

<input type="submit" class="submit"/>
```

.submit - in css . means class , so i created submit class with set of attributes
and applied that class to the submit tag, using class attribute