# why the button is not taking the style?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Hi I have the code where i have two button in the div using jquery mobile but while put some style on the button its not taking the Style.Then how to achieve that using jquery mobile?

```css
.ui-block-b .ui-btn .ui-input-btn .ui-corner-all .ui-shadow {
    background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="ui-grid-a">
  
  
<div>
```

Comment: Your CSS doesn't correspond with your HTML, you have no `.ui-shadow` in your code.

Comment: where is `.ui-btn` inside `.ui-block-b`    ????

Comment: your button doesn't have a class, it's the <div> that is getting the class, not the <input> so put your class in your input

Comment: @kmsdev: really? Please, forget on `important`.

Comment: I misread the code .)

Comment: @snehasish, check out this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950238/can-you-style-html-form-buttons-with-css

Comment: @SnehasishDas: below you have an answer. You used bad selector, I added an explanation how to.

Answer (score 1):

If you have element with multiple classes (regarding comments at question), like

```
<div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
```

and you need to set styles, you have two options:

First is to set background to one of these classes, eg.

```
.ui-corner-all {background: yellow;}
```

The second one, if you want to target just element with all classes, the correct selector is

```
.ui-btn.ui-input-btn.ui-corner-all.ui-shadow {background: yellow}
```

Your attempt `.ui-block-b .ui-btn .ui-input-btn .ui-corner-all .ui-shadow` tried to find `.ui-shadow` in `.ui-corner-all` in `.ui-input-btn` in `.ui-btn` in `.ui-block-b` like:

```
<div class="ui-block-b">
    <div class="ui-btn">
        <div class="ui-input-btn">
            <div class="ui-corner-all">
                <button class="ui-shadow">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This HTML markup doesn't exist.

Comment: @SnehasishDas: But in your fiddle there is no `.ui-input-btn` class. The color is light because of `opacity: .1`.

Comment: @SnehasishDas: try to do something yourself. It's so easy how to override one value by second one.

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly written the css code. Try this.

```css
.ui-block-b input[type="submit"]{
           background:yellow;
        }
```

```html
    <div data-role="ui-grid-a">

      <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:50%">
        <input type="button" id="Previous" value="Previous" onclick="window.location.href='%bind(:24)'" />
      </div>
      <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:50%">
     <input type="Submit" id="Submit" value="Save and Next" />
      </div>
    <div>
```

Comment: Actually i didn't get what do  you want exactly.

Comment: Yes, that i have made in that snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `,` between if you want to give css to multiple class.

And use `>` if you want to give css to input inside div.

```css
.ui-block-b, .ui-btn, .ui-input-btn, .ui-corner-all, .ui-shadow{
       background:yellow;
    }

.ui-block-a > input{
  background:yellow;
  }
```

```html
<div data-role="ui-grid-a">

  <div class="ui-block-a" style="width:50%">
    <input type="button" id="Previous" value="Previous" onclick="window.location.href='%bind(:24)'" />
  </div>
  <div class="ui-block-b" style="width:50%">
 <input type="Submit" id="Submit" value="Save and Next" />
  </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score -1):

`.ui-btn .ui-input-btn .ui-corner-all .ui-shadow` these classes are non-existant.

Comment: It's enough to only address one class, no need to write all of them. It would be better if you post a link or a working example.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Nico, you might want to read the question and my answer again.