# Sorting div asc desc by content

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

If i have formed html with divs [Here example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpeGRJ)

```
          <div>            
            <a href='#' class='auction-position block'>
                <div class='company-logo block'>Sort By Name</div>
                <div class='company-data block'>Sort By ID</div>
                <div class='auction-information block'>
                    <div class='auction-date block'>Sort By Date</div>
                    <div class='amount-days block'>Sort By Km</div>
                </div>
                <div class='amount-lots block'>Sort By Amount</div>
                <div class='rates block'>
                    <time datetime='00:00:26444641'>Sort By Time</time>
                </div>
                <div class='clear'></div>
            </a>
           </div>
```

How To sort divs by pressing on "Sort By .." ? It is possible to do wiht Javascript or jquery?

Comment: I have written an answer for a similair question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31390227/sorting-elements-with-jquery-using-data-attributes/31390513#31390513 Please have a look, it might be useful.

Comment: Yes man thanks that is what i need. So if you write the answer here i will acept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change that into a table and use DataTables jquery plugin.
https://www.datatables.net/

Here is and example of the javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#table_id').DataTable({
           false,
           false, 
           false
        });
    } );
```